# ffmpeg convert wmv to ASF (MP43+WMAv9)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

Sorry for my very limited knowledge of codecs and ffmpeg, but... I need to convert a WMV file with these specs:

`.wmv 1280*720 (16:9) WMV3 = Windows Media Video 9; 192 Kbps, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, Windows Media Audio 9.2`

to

`.wmv 1280*720 (16:9) MP43 = msmpeg4v3; 192 Kbps, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, Windows Media Audio 9.2`

Is it possible using ffmpeg (or any other alternative free tool in case), and how can I do?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have a video with these codecs to test, so try `ffmpeg -i test.wmv -c:a wmav2 -c:v msmpeg4v3 test.wmv` and let me know if it works, so I can post an answer. If video will have no sound or command will fail, then it's impossible with default ffmpeg build due to Windows Media Audio 9.2 in original video.

Comment: will use Windows Media Audio V8... is there a way to use WMA9.2 like the original?

Comment: I have no idea how your reply is related to the question or my comment. Use clear sentences when replying, please. Did the command work? What/who/when will use WMA8?

Comment: The converted file (using msmpeg4v3) will use WMA v8 with ``-c:a wmav2``. It seems there is no way with FFmpeg to use WMA v9.2 like the original video I wanted to convert.

Comment: That's what your question asks for though "to (...) Windows Media Audio V8". Edit the question if that's not what you need. Unless you're stating that it fails to decode the sound, which would make sense as 9.2 is `wmav3`  in theory, which isn't supported by `ffmpeg` by default.

Comment: You edited the title I see but forgot about the "Windows Media Audio 8" part. It's impossible with ffmpeg then, unless you can find a build that includes `wmav3`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right I didn't copy&paste correctly. Question fixed. In the meanwhile I've learned it's indeed not available through ffmpeg, and can't find even (reasonably) paid programs able to convert to msmpeg4v3+WMA9... at least I can't find one ATM...

Comment: After a quick Google, Windows Media Encoder 9 seems to be the only option for that hopeless format. It doesn't even work under Windows 10 apparently though.